# Is there any guarantee that the algorithm behind java.util.Collections.shuffle() remains unchanged in future Java releases?

Tags: java, random, shuffle

Is the following program guaranteed to produce a list with the same contents and ordering in future java releases?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(42));
  }
}
```

The javadoc of the `java.util.Random` class guarantees that it will always return the same random numbers if intialized with the same seed in all future java releases.

But are there any guarantees regarding the algorithm behind the `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` utility function? The Javadoc for this utility function does not say anything about this.

I need this guarantee, because I want to be sure that persisted data will not be  useless with any future java release.

Comment: What are you persisting? This sounds like a very odd requirement to me.

Comment: Either immediately copy the shuffle algorithm or make a run time test on small data. A JUnit test in your main app too. Test it on Android too. I would say if money is involved, do it yourself.

Comment: I would suggest you to implement your own function to keep it stable. There's no garantee at all that this will be stable with future/others java implementations.

Comment: The answer is in the question IMHO. You say that there is no guarantee, but ask if there is a guarantee... I agree that the only guarantee is to make your own method. Here's open jdk's implementation FWIW: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Random%29

Comment: No guarantee. But the collections framework is and will be designed to ensure interoperability between the core interfaces https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interoperability/compatibility.html

Comment: This general guideline may also proove useful to you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interoperability/api-design.html

Comment: There is a good implementation at `http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/Shuffle.java.html` so just use that one.

Comment: @vefthym Sometimes there are guarantees which are not explicitly documented in the javadoc.

Comment: @Daniel, unless they're documented _somewhere,_ they can't really be called guarantees :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet That isn't an odd requirement. It's very much fine. He might use it to generate the same random number sequence every time using the same seed. This helps him not to store the key anywhere. He could just create the key then and there. Lot of possibilites.

Comment: @UmaKanth: The requirement for a random number generator to create the same sequence from the same seed seems reasonable. Persisting a shuffled collection seems less so to me, which is why I asked for more context (which still hasn't appeared).

Comment: @JonSkeet The reason using a shuffled collection is that he wanted to **restrict** the random values to a confined set of values while generating a key. Probably a key without few letters.

Comment: @UmaKanth: Where did you get that information from? I don't see it in comments or the question. Besides, that doesn't seem to require a shuffled collection to me: take an unshuffled collection, use a key for the seed, and take random values from the collection that way. No need for anything beyond guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am implementing something simular to [link](http://hashids.org), but with added functionality. If you look at the javascript code implementation at [link](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.js/blob/master/lib/hashids.js) you will see, that there is a consistentShuffle method. And I wondered if I could use Collections.shuffle() with a seeded Random instance.

Comment: @DanielK.: I'm afraid I'm not going to read 350 lines of Javascript to try to understand why you think it's required. Please add appropriate context in the question - I strongly suspect that there's no real need for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for presenting Javascript code when the question was about java. Have a look at the consistentShuffle() method of a java implementation [link](https://github.com/dkay/jhashids/blob/master/src/de/kaymx/jhashids/JHashIds.java) I did some months ago. If you want to prove that my requirement is useless, then you will have to read that code. I won't start explaining any implementation details here. My question was very clear and I got enough feedback to move on with my work.

Comment: @DanielK.: How can the implementation of a method determine whether the method is required or not? The implementation of a method can't explain *why* it's being called - and as that code has precisely 0 comments, there's no justification there, either. I'm glad you've got the feedback you require, but I'd still urge you to reconsider whether or not this is actually something you should be doing.

Comment: @JonSkeet As far as I can tell, the idea is to reversibly scramble a list of values, which sort of explains the requirement. (Though why the existing methods of encoding/decoding aren't sufficient is a different question :))

Comment: @JonSkeet The code I shown you is a implementation of the hashids javascript library for java because in my opinion the already available implementation was to slow and if i remember correctly even incorrect. The question came from a new implementation I am working on right now which has more features and is different in many ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no explicit guarantee, as you say.

On the other hand, the existence of a separate `Collections.shuffle(List,Random)` would suggest that the intention is that this method will always return the same order when invoked with a `Random` in an identical state. (This is useful to create repeatable tests for example.)

So it's a bit of a grey area.

But if core functionality depends on it and you want to be absolutely sure, you can implement the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (or rather, the more efficient Durstenfeld algorithm) yourself, it's simple. It's so simple that it's definitely not worth taking the (probably small) risk that `Collections.shuffle()` will change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that's always been drilled into me at large development shops is that, once something is documented as behaving a certain way, it had better always behave that way, unless you want to suffer the wrath of your clients.

Conversely, if something isn't documented, clients have no expectations that it should remain the same.

I believe this falls squarely into the second category, the Java documentation makes no guarantees.

Hence, if you *need* such a guarantee, your safest bet is to write your own shuffling code.